# How to erase encryption keys from memory in C#?

Tags: encryption, .net

I was browsing through the Cure53 audits and found a mention of 'Secure key deletion ineffective (Medium)' on pg. 3 [here](https://cure53.de/pentest-report_safing-jess.pdf). The Cure53 team was saying that there's no real way to erase sensitive data in memory using Go.

Is there a way of doing this in C#? C# is also limited in this respect by the garbage collection, but surely there must be some method of erasing byte arrays and such.

Comment: Sounds like [C# has the same problem](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/212917/3365).

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't erasing a byte array. You can erase a byte array. The problem is for example that the GC of .NET could have moved the byte array during the defrag phase, so there is a phantom copy of your array somewhere in memory. You could solve this by pinning the array so that it isn't moved by the GC. This could solve the

> However, the tactic used in order to achieve key erasure is likely ineffective, due to the
> limitations of the Go’s garbage collection-based memory management model1

but it won't solve the

> Furthermore, it does not attempt to target residual values, such as intermediate
> computations, which thus may remain in memory.

When you do public key crypto, you must do many big-number math operations. The intermediate results are somewhere. A library securely written should handle all these intermediate results as securely as the initial values (symmetric encryption is often easier: the common algorithms can work directly in the buffer that will be used for the output). But you must write the library in this way :-)

And all these things won't really protect you. If an external process has access to the memory of your process, it can continuously check around until it finds the keys... Before or later your keys will be in memory plainly unencrypted. For this reason in the end the .NET `SecureString` is not-the-final-solution: https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md

> It just makes the window getting the plain text shorter; it doesn't fully prevent it as .NET still has to convert the string to a plain text representation.

A real solution must exist at the OS level, or even better at the OS plus processor level. Protected memory that can only be read by a single process, or even better is write-only and all the encryption is done at the OS/Processor level (a trojan could inject itself in your process otherwise)

In the end the only really good solution is probably an [Hardware Security Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module):

> A hardware security module (HSM) is a physical computing device that safeguards and manages digital keys, performs encryption and decryption functions for digital signatures, strong authentication and other cryptographic functions. These modules traditionally come in the form of a plug-in card or an external device that attaches directly to a computer or network server.

But then we are going outside the scope of "how can I securely program my application or my library". We are outsorcing the problem.

Comment: Is there any example of pinning?

Comment: @kelalaka `GCHandle gc = GCHandle.Alloc(yourByteArray, GCHandleType.Pinned)`. Remember to unpin it, otherwise it will remain pinned! So do a `try { pin(bytearray); do_work() } finally { unpin }` or implement a `IDisposable` + `destructor` pattern (a GCHandle is like an unmanaged resource). Best is to encapsulate the byte array in a `class PinnedByteArray : IDisposable` that implements the full `IDisposable` + `destructor` pattern and that in the Dispose() clears the array with 0x00... I should have some code somewhere... I'll take a look

Comment: @kelalaka mmmh... I've taken a look... I've found the code, but it is too much intermixed with other code, and is split in like 5-10 files (there are many support methods, plus I VirtualLocked the memory pages so that they couldn't be swapped out by Windows, and just keeping track of which pages are VirtualLocked and which aren't is a chore, because a page in Windows is 4kb, and you could have multiple arrays in the same page), so I needed a tracker to handle this

Comment: For me a link is enough, however, those will make the answer more complete and the title is generic to be found so that others may get help. Thanks.

Comment: @kelalaka No... It was a project of mine that was never ended... It isn't on github, and in the end it isn't "peer reviewd", so it could be snake oil.

Comment: I see, I hope you could perfectly finish it in a near future.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading an encryption key into memory and trying to erase it after use, consider not loading the key into memory at all.

On Windows, you can achieve this by storing the key using a [CNG key store provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccertenroll/cng-key-storage-providers) and using CNG to carry out all cryptographic operations. Unlike CryptoNG (and many other crypto libraries), CNG [offloads crytographic operations to LSASS](https://jpassing.com/2021/06/22/why-use-cng-instead-of-cryptoapi-to-store-keys/) so that the keys aren't even loaded into the memory of your process.

Most cryptography classes in the .NET library have a CNG and a CryptoAPI variant, for example `RSACng` (CNG) and `RSACryptoServiceProvider` (CryptoAPI).